# Using Stripe to process payments on server

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I have a vue.js project as a UI which sends requests to my .NET Core API app to process typical CRUD requests.

I have been following the documentation on https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously

I've set up the payment method creation on the vue.js project which creates an identifier for the users card details, which is then sent to the API to be processed/completed:

```
[HttpPost("buy")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Buy(PaymentRequest request)
{
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _stripeSettings.Key;
    var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
    {
       PaymentMethod = request.paymentMethod,
       Amount = 300,
       Currency = "gbp",
       ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
       Confirm = true
    };
    var intent = await _paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(options);
    return Ok(intent.ClientSecret);
}
```

I am then able to view this successful transaction on my Stripe dashboard.

I can't find anything useful online, but is there a way to process all of this in the backend without my frontend knowing anything about stripe? The reason I ask, is because I would like some sort of seperation of concerns as if I was to change the integration for accepting payments in future I wouldn't need to update the frontend.

Comment: Anything that doesn't involve Stripe.js for collecting card details is going to open you up to [PCI compliance requirements](https://stripe.com/guides/pci-compliance) that Stripe.js covers you for. I'd suggest either planning to always collect those details on the front end with Stripe.js, or contacting Stripe directly to discuss other options in context.

Comment: @taintedzodiac This is understandable. Is there any documentation regarding the best method to integrate the stripe.js with vue.js? I've had a look through and can only see reference to React. P

Comment: Unfortuantely there isn't a first-party Vue library for Stripe.js yet. Articles like https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/integrating-with-stripe-client-basics-c9f188329143 exist but really I'd suggest following one of those currently.